# Why are CMYK colors in Pillow out of 250 instead of 100?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

CMYK color values are typically set as percentages out of 100, for example CMYK(100, 0, 70, 50) makes dark green.

However it seems in Pillow one must multiply each value by 2.5 to get the same color. In the images below, the top and bottom "Hello World" text is set using the following code:

```
myImageDraw.text((20, 20), "Hello World", fill=(250, 0, 175, 125), font=ImageFont.truetype(montserratRegular, 300))
myImageDraw.text((20, 300), "Hello World", fill=(100, 0, 70, 50), font=ImageFont.truetype(montserratRegular, 300))
```

For reference I've included an image of the text created in a separate design program with the color set as CMYK(100, 0, 70, 50). As you can see it matches the top text created by pillow (values multiplied by 2.5), instead of 2.5.

I'm trying to figure out why Pillow uses CMYK colors as percentages of 250 instead of 100.

[image: Hello World text in two shades of green created in Python and Pillow]

[image: Hello World text created in Adobe InDesign]

Comment: They're out of 255, for the same reason that RGB values are usually out of 255 - because that's the range possible with an 8-bit value in the underlying data. Any tools you're accustomed to working with (Photoshop?) that give you a value out of 100, are trying to make things friendly for you.

Comment: That said, "why did the authors of this tool make this particular design decision?" is off topic for Stack Overflow. You should ask *them*, not us.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: N/A, the authors made no such decision.

Comment: @martineau, ...how so? Just because something is the sane, reasonable, widely-if-not-universally-accepted default doesn't mean that it isn't a decision.

Comment: @Charles: What I meant it's N/A was because the range isn't 250 out of 100 so the whole premise is wrong. Actually the "decision" was probably made by what's commonly in image file formats coupled with the precision of an 8-bit quantity.

Comment: @martineau Gotcha. I was defending (and remain in agreement with) the idea of "why is software-tool X designed in way Y?" is generally off-topic here (whereas "how do I implement Z in software-tool X, given the challenges posed by Y?" is in accordance with the meat-and-potatoes core of what we do). I didn't mean to imply that the OP's assertions were correct.

Comment: (Undirected aside: In my alternate persona as a hobbyist AV engineer, I work with a lot of content that has more than 8 bits per channel; things generally do _end up_ there, but having more precision means there's more room for aggressive color grading without causing banding or other unwanted behaviors when stretching out a small part of the gamut).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMYK traditionally uses 0-100 because it measures ink coverage percentages. But in software, that's not super useful and doesn't make the best use of memory.

Pillow, like a lot of color software is using 8-bit color here. This means you have values from 0 to 255 or 8-bits per channel.

Pillow's [concepts](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html) documentation here is explicit:

> Each pixel uses the full range of the bit depth. So a 1-bit pixel has
> a range of 0-1, an 8-bit pixel has a range of 0-255 and so on.

...

> CMYK (4x8-bit pixels, color separation)

Comment: It's usually spelled "CMYK". Please cite authoritative source that 0-100 is traditional range.

Comment: Citations aren't expected, I just asked for one. I have 30+ years of professional graphics software experience.

Comment: My experience is that in software they are usually expressed as quantities in the range of 0–255, just like RGB values. They *correspond* to floating-point values in the continuous range 0–100% of the maximum value any component can have, but in much finer 1/256th (0.00390625) increments, rather than courser 1/100th (.1000) ones. In the relatively rare floating-point image file formats I seen, both RGB and CMYK *are* expressed a percentages in order to take advantage of the maximum resolution of that numeric format. Regardless, FWIW, I think you've posted a good answer.

Comment: I think it depends on what you mean by "expressed". 8-bit color is *represented* as 8-bit ints in computers. I have rarely seen CMYK *expressed* as anything other than percentages *to the user* in the interface…that's how I interpret "expressed". As far as pro tools like the Adobe suite, when you switch to CMYK, you switch to percentages. CMYK is also expressed in percentages in Pantone swatch books and on sites like https://color.adobe.com when you switch to CMKY mode.  I think that's because if you are working in CMYK it's expected you are thinking about tints, halftones, and ink, not bits.

Comment: You're right about the Photoshop's human interface. By "expressed" I meant "manifest" at the *software* interface level. Most of my work at Adobe involved working on graphics software libraries — I was in the CoreTech department that developed and maintained a number them that were used by multiple applications, so that's how I relate to this question about PIL/Pillow's interface.

Comment: Interesting @martineau — I bet that was fascinating work. I would take it a step beyond the interface, though. The percentages shown in the interface represents real-world ink-on-paper color that predates digital color. The percentages were here before the computer. Obviously once you want to represent this in a computer you need to turn it into bits somehow, regardless of the color model. I *think* this is the source of confusion the OP was asking about.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right about the OP's source of confusion on that point, as they do say "…values are typically set as percentages out of 100". For printing, which is typically were CMYK color specifications are used they are percentages for RGM, not so much — although in Adobe's PostScript graphics language both the `setrgbcolor` and `setcmykcolor` function required arguments in the 0-100 (floating-point) range. Dunno where the OP got the 250 from…

Comment: OP here. I got 250 from just fiddling with the colors in Pillow until they look about the same as Photoshop. I knew RGB is out of 255 and I should have known something was up since the 250 number is so similar. Anyways, thanks everyone for your help